# Arrows chemical equations

Tags: equations, arrows, chemistry

I want to write the following equation; note the arrow underneath `BaSO_4` and the `H_2O` over the `\longrightarrow`.

[image]

Is that possible with the `chemist` package, which I already use for my chemical equations? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No problem. Could you add a link to the `chemist` package? It doesn't seem to be on CTAN...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are two alternatives I'd consider. The first is the well known [`mhchem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\ce{Na2SO4 ->[H2O] Na+ + SO4^2-}

\ce{(2Na+,SO4^2- ) + (Ba^2+, 2Cl- ) -> BaSO4 v + 2NaCl}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second is the `chemformula` package from the [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) bundle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}

\ch{Na2SO4 ->[ H2O ] Na+ + SO4^2-}

\ch{( 2 Na+ ,SO4^2- ) + (Ba^2+ , 2 Cl- ) -> BaSO4 v + 2 NaCl}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Their syntax is slightly different and both are bit picky about spaces that need to be there in order to parse the input, however in different places... you'll also notice small differences in the output for example with regard to spacing.

But since you've mentioned the `chemist` package (which is part of the [XyMTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xymtex) bundle): the reactions are also possible with it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemist}
\begin{document}

\begin{chemmath}
  Na_{2}SO_{4}
  \reactrarrow{0pt}{1.5cm}{\ChemForm{H_2O}}{}
  Na^{+} + SO_{4}^{2-}
\end{chemmath}

\begin{chemmath}
  (2 Na^{+},SO_{4}^{2-}) + (Ba^{2+},2 Cl^{-})
  \reactrarrow{0pt}{1cm}{}{}
  BaSO_{4} + 2 NaCl
\end{chemmath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: isn't there a way to represent the precipitate arrow like the one in my question?

Comment: @HediNaily with [TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) this should be possible. I don't know any chemistry package that provides something like it, though...

Answer (score 12):

Here is a [chemfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{Na_2SO_4}
\arrow{->[\footnotesize\chemfig{H_2O}]}
\chemfig{Na^+}\+\chemfig{SO_2^{-}}
\schemestop

\bigskip

\schemestart
(2\chemfig{Na^+}, \chemfig{SO_4^{2-}})
\+
(\chemfig{Ba^{2+}}, 2\chemfig{Cl^{-}})
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
\chemname[1pt]{\chemfig{BaSO_4}}{\chemfig{-[,0.75]-[5,.3,,,-stealth]}}\+2\chemfig{NaCl}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those who may be interested and looking for a list of 'Known (LaTeX) Chemistry Packages', there is an excellent, albeit a bit dated by internet standards (appears to be ~9 years old) summary of chemistry related LaTeX packages:

"This is intended to be a complete list of chemistry related LaTeX packages. Still — nobody is perfect. So probably there are packages missing. If you know of any package that is missing, please let me know and I will add it to the list." - CLEMENS' LATEX CORNER

https://mychemistry.eu/known-packages/

A total of 47 packages by my count are listed!

Note: The CLEMENS' LATEX CORNER is NOT my Wordpress web site, nor do I have any control over, or connection to, the website. If you have comments on the list of 'Known (LaTeX) Chemistry Packages', you can enter your comments at the bottom of the CLEMENS' LATEX CORNER web page at the above URL.

Enjoy!