# Chemical Equations

Tags: chemistry, mhchem

I need to include chemical equations in my thesis project. However, when I render my thesis with all the equations included, LaTeX cannot seem to process what seems to be such a 'big' file and the 'run' process never ends. I tried running a few equations as a new document, however, I come across the same problem.

Could anybody suggest a way around this?

I have attached my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage,setspace}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

    \subparagraph{Top Reaction Pathways for \ce{C6H6} production:}
    \begin{align}
    \ce{C2H3+ C4H4 <-->[2.56e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H6}\\
    \ce{FULVENE <-->[2.36e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H6}\\
    \ce{p-C3H4 + C3H3<-->[6.03e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H6}\\
    \ce{a-C3H4 + C3H3<-->[1.25e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H6}\\
    \ce{C3H3 <-->[3.67e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H6}
    \end{align}

    \subparagraph{Top Reaction Pathways for \ce{C6H5} production:}
    \begin{align}
    \ce{C6H6 + OH <-->[1.16e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H5}\\
    \ce{C6H6 + CH3<-->[7.05e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H5}\\
    \ce{C6H6CH2CH2 <-->[4.16e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H5}
    \end{align}

    \subparagraph{Top Reaction Pathways for \ce{A1O} production:}
    \begin{align}
    \ce{C6H6OH + C3H6 <-->[1.38e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H6O}\\
    \ce{C6H6OH + H<-->[1.02e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H6O}\\
    \ce{C6H5 + O2<-->[9.8e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H6O}
    \end{align}

    \subparagraph{Top Reaction Pathways for \ce{C6H6C2H3} production:}
    \begin{align}
    \ce{C6H5 + C2H3 <-->[6.48e\textsuperscript{-16}] C6H6C2H3}\\
    \ce{C5H5 + C3H3<-->[8.9e\textsuperscript{-11}]C6H6C2H3}
    \end{align}

    \subparagraph{Top Reaction Pathways for \ce{C6H6CHCH} production:}
    \begin{align}
    \ce{C6H6C2H3 + H <-->[6.36e\textsuperscript{-12}]C6H6CHCH}\\
    \ce{C6H6C2H3 + OH<-->[5.02e\textsuperscript{-12}]C6H6CHCH}\\
    \ce{C6H6C2H3 + O<-->[1.64e\textsuperscript{-12}]C6H6CHCH}
    \end{align}

    \subparagraph{Top Reaction Pathways for \ce{A2} production:}
    \begin{align}
    \ce{C2H3 + A1C2H <—>[5.6e\textsuperscript{-12}]A2}\\
    \ce{C3H3 + C7H5<—>[2.7e\textsuperscript{-11}]A2}\\
    \ce{C5H5 <-—>[9e\textsuperscript{-12}]A2}
    \end{align}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: Odds are it's an infinite loop.  Try removing parts until you find where the problem is.  BTW, there are packages for this.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142865/arrows-chemical-equations for examples.

Answer (score 6):

This solution makes the following changes to your code:

1. The last three equations include emdashes in the syntax for the arrow. I replaced them with dashes (-).
2. I added the chemmacros package to use its reactions module. This gives me the ability to create reaction environments for each group of equations.
3. I specified by using `chemmacros` `\chemsetup` to use `mhchem`'s chemformula macro: `\ce`. `Chemmacro`'s equivalent is `\ch`. This makes loading mhchem redundant, although I left it here in case it is required for another reason.
4. I aligned the equations in each reaction environment by adding the tab character `&`

The result is this, followed by the code. Good luck with your thesis.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage,setspace}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
    modules = all,
    formula = mhchem
}

\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

    \subparagraph{Top Reaction Pathways for \ce{C6H6} production:}
    \begin{reactions}
    C2H3+ C4H4 &<-->[2.56e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H6\\
    FULVENE &<-->[2.36e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H6\\
    p-C3H4 + C3H3 &<-->[6.03e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H6\\
    a-C3H4 + C3H3 &<-->[1.25e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H6\\
    C3H3 &<-->[3.67e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H6
    \end{reactions}

    \subparagraph{Top Reaction Pathways for \ce{C6H5} production:}
    \begin{reactions}
    C6H6 + OH &<-->[1.16e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H5\\
    C6H6 + CH3 &<-->[7.05e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H5\\
    C6H6CH2CH2 &<-->[4.16e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H5
    \end{reactions}

    \subparagraph{Top Reaction Pathways for \ce{A1O} production:}
    \begin{reactions}
    C6H6OH + C3H6 &<-->[1.38e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H6O\\
    C6H6OH + H &<-->[1.02e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H6O\\
    C6H5 + O2 &<-->[9.8e\textsuperscript{-10}] C6H6O
    \end{reactions}

    \subparagraph{Top Reaction Pathways for \ce{C6H6C2H3} production:}
    \begin{reactions}
    C6H5 + C2H3 &<-->[6.48e\textsuperscript{-16}] C6H6C2H3\\
    C5H5 + C3H3 &<-->[8.9e\textsuperscript{-11}] C6H6C2H3
    \end{reactions}

    \subparagraph{Top Reaction Pathways for \ce{C6H6CHCH} production:}
    \begin{reactions}
    C6H6C2H3 + H &<-->[6.36e\textsuperscript{-12}] C6H6CHCH\\
    C6H6C2H3 + OH &<-->[5.02e\textsuperscript{-12}] C6H6CHCH\\
    C6H6C2H3 + O &<-->[1.64e\textsuperscript{-12}] C6H6CHCH
    \end{reactions}

    \subparagraph{Top Reaction Pathways for \ce{A2} production:}
    \begin{reactions}
    C2H3 + A1C2H &<-->[5.6e\textsuperscript{-12}] A2\\
    C3H3 + C7H5 &<-->[2.7e\textsuperscript{-11}] A2\\
    C5H5 &<-->[9e\textsuperscript{-12}] A2
    \end{reactions}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With your example, I get `mhchem error: "cf/unexpected-input"` on my system.
 You should fix 2 things.

- In the last 3 lines, remove the wide dashes with normal ones.
- Make sure all arrows are surrounded by spaces, put a space before `<-->` and a space after `]`.

I would also recommend to insert a few `&` in order to make proper use of the align environment.